# Plotting reward curve in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm wondering how to plot reward curves in reinforcement learning.

Especially, my simulated environment has significant randomness.
So there are so many zig-zag patterns in raw data of reward even though the output policy is converged.

Is there any way to plot in this case?

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid I don't get your problem. Why not just plotting the reward you receive at each episode? If the policy converges, after a while you should see an increase in the reward, even though there might be those zig zags st start.